# How to change the src's value by jquery?

Tags: jquery

the html structure:

```
<div class="myimages">
   <div id="mainimg"><img src="images/Pic/1.jpg"></div>
   <div id="addimg">
      <li class="addimg"><img src="images/Pic/1_01.jpg"></li>
       <li class="addimg"><img src="images/Pic/1_02.jpg"></li>
        <li class="addimg"><img src="images/Pic/1_03.jpg"></li>

    </div>
</div>
```

How to change the img src's value(which in `<div id="mainimg">` ) when the mouse hover on the li which in `addimg` by jquery.namely, when the mouse hover on the  second li,    `<div id="mainimg"><img src="images/Pic/1.jpg"></div>` will change to    `<div id="mainimg"><img src="images/Pic/1_02.jpg"></div>`. when on the first or the third li. the change is the same. thank you

Comment: You might want to familiarize yourself with the manipulation functions of jquery. http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$('li.addimg').hover(function() {
   var src = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
   $('#mainimg img').attr('src', src);
});
```

We are catching the hover event on those li's and then grabbing the src of the img inside of the li that the hover is triggered on, and setting it as the new src of the img inside of the div with id "mainimg"

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.addimg').mouseover(function() {
  $('.mainimg img').attr('src', $(this).find('img').attr('src'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve it aas follow

```
$(".adding").hover( function() {
       var hoverImg = HoverImgOf($(this).attr("src"));
       $("#mainimg img").attr("src", hoverImg);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this:

```
jQuery('li.addimg').onmouseover(function() {
  jQuery('#mainimg img').attr('src', jQuery(this).children('img').attr('src'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't want the image to change back to `1.jpg` when you move the mouse off the `li`, you can bind an event handler to the `mouseover` event and use [`replaceWith`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) to replace the image with the one in the `li`:

```
$("li.addimg").mouseover(function() {
    $("#mainimg img").replaceWith($(this).find("img"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

http://jsbin.com/ifofot/edit#javascript,html

```
$('#addimg li.addimg img').on('mouseover',function (){
$(this).parents(".myimages").find("#mainimg img").attr('src',$(this).attr('src'));


});
```