# How to animate gif on current viewport/screen in website

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, viewport, gif

I m building a website where i m using some gif file but the gifs start animating as soon as the page loads. I want them to trigger as the user scroll on to the particular gif section i.e current viewport. See example: http://www.invisionapp.com/

I have searched the entire internet but couldnt get the simplest way of doint that. Anybody having any idea please assist.

Comment: It looks like you need waypoints. Did you try anything?

Comment: I tried with few jquery stuffs, Not working out :(

Comment: Update your question, and put the code you've tried so far (html + js).

Answer (score 0):

The website you have shared is using something known as lazyload. It will load images/videos only on scroll.

For some lazyload alternatives, please refer to these:

[- How to lazy load natively](https://web.dev/native-lazy-loading/)

[- Vanilla lazy load library on Github](https://github.com/verlok/vanilla-lazyload)

Answer (score -1):

What you can do is use two images, one static and one which has an animation. So, when user scrolls over target, in your case viewport, then, you replace a static image with the animated gif image.

Comment: Hi Pramod, thnx for the help. can you provide a sample code to swap these images ?

Comment: @BeginnerKid you are only required to change src value of image tag when your event is triggered.

Comment: yes i got your point. But how do i change the src value in the current viewport ??

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800464/how-to-change-the-srcs-value-by-jquery

Comment: Thats for mouseover/hover event. I want for current viewport bro, details of which is hardly available on internet

Comment: you want to trigger this when user scroll page, right.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737937/detect-if-a-scroll-event-is-triggered-manually-in-jquery